# why a double number less than DBL_MIN can be printed?

Tags: c++, double, range, ieee-754

I assign `0.4543543234343654632452452525254e-323` to a `double` variable `a` and print it, although it is less than `DBL_MIN`, it can still be assigned and printed.

```
DBL_MAX: 1.79769e+308
FLT_MAX: 3.40282e+38
DBL_MIN: 2.22507e-308
FLT_MIN: 1.17549e-38
a: 4.94066e-324
```

Why this happens?

Comment: @flatmouse: `DBL_MIN` is not the minimum value in the sense of sign, but in the sense of magnitude, the smallest value larger (or smaller) than zero. So, basically, the number which is as near to zero as possible. The sign is irrelevant since it's a specific bit.

Comment: right click > mark and copy the output text. No need to capture the screenshot which may rot if the server dies

Comment: Lots of good floating point stuff in this blog (not mine) https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/thats-not-normalthe-performance-of-odd-floats/ and https://randomascii.wordpress.com/category/floating-point/

Comment: thanks for all your help and advice!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually `DBL_MIN` is not the smallest value but the smallest [*normalized* value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Double_precision) that is representable.

The difference is the leading digit with is 1 for normalized values, while it's 0 for denormal numbers. Mind that [denormal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) could suffer from sever performance issues on hardware with floating processing unit which is not able to manage them in hardware.

But your value, `0.454354e-323`, which corresponds to `4.545354e-324` is smaller than the smallest denormal number representble with a `double`, indeed it gets rounded to `4.94066e-324` which is the real smallest number which can be stored in a `double`.

Comment: @flatmouse: `DBL_MIN` is not the smallest number that can be represented in a `double` value so there is nothing strange in the output of OP's program.

Comment: @flatmouse maybe you misread the question - it seems to me that this answer answers the question and yours has nothing to do with it

Answer (score -1):

The IEEE 754-1985 behavior is easier to understand by looking at the bits directly.

The [following program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/182f36c3c45dd59c) shows the sign, mantissa and exponent for each number and the bit pattern for each.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <iomanip>
#include <bitset>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>

using Values = std::tuple<double,std::string>;
using MyMap = std::unordered_map<std::string,Values>;

std::string convert_to_string(double val)
{
    auto ptr{reinterpret_cast<const unsigned long long*>(&val)};
    auto ival{*ptr};
    unsigned long long mask{1ULL << 63};
    std::string bitstring;
    for (size_t i{0}; i<64; ++i) {
        auto bitval{(ival&mask)>0};
        mask >>= 1;
        bitval? bitstring.push_back('1') : bitstring.push_back('0');
    }

    return bitstring;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,std::pair<std::string,Values> mypair)
{
    auto name{mypair.first};
    auto values{mypair.second};
    auto dvalue{std::get<0>(values)};
    auto bitsetvalue{std::get<1>(values)};
    char sign_symbol{bitsetvalue.substr(0,1)=="0"?'+':'-'};
    std::bitset<1> sign{bitsetvalue.substr(0,1)};
    std::bitset<11> biased_exponent{bitsetvalue.substr(1,11)};
    std::bitset<52> mantissa{bitsetvalue.substr(12,52)};
    auto mantissa_value{mantissa.to_ullong()};
    double mantissa_value_double{static_cast<double>(mantissa_value)};
    auto biased_exponent_value{static_cast<signed long long>(biased_exponent.to_ulong())};
    bool denormal{biased_exponent_value==0};
    std::string denormal_text{denormal?"denormal":""};
    signed long long exponent_value{denormal?-1022:biased_exponent_value-1023};
    std::string mantissa_with_leading_digit{std::string((denormal?"0.":"1.")) + mantissa.to_string()};
    double mantissa_with_leading_digit_value{double{denormal?0.0F:1.0F}+(mantissa_value_double * std::pow(2.0F,-52.0F))};
    std::bitset<11> unbiased_exponent{static_cast<unsigned long long>(std::abs(exponent_value))};
    char exponent_sign_symbol{exponent_value<0?'-':' '};

    std::cout << std::setw(60) << name << std::setw(20) << dvalue << '\n';
    std::cout << std::setw(60) << "Binary  (biased   exponent, hidden  leading binary digit)" << std::setw(30) << sign << std::setw(15) << biased_exponent << std::setw(10) << denormal_text << std::setw(60) << mantissa << '\n';
    std::cout << std::setw(60) << "Binary  (unbiased exponent, visible leading binary digit)" << std::setw(30) << sign << std::setw(4) << exponent_sign_symbol << unbiased_exponent << std::setw(10) << denormal_text << std::setw(60) << mantissa_with_leading_digit << '\n';
    std::cout << std::setw(60) << "Decimal (biased   exponent)                              " << std::setw(30) << sign_symbol << std::setw(15) << biased_exponent_value << std::setw(10) << denormal_text << std::setw(60) << mantissa_with_leading_digit_value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::setw(60) << "Decimal (unbiased exponent)                              " << std::setw(30) << sign_symbol << std::setw(15) << exponent_value << std::setw(10) << denormal_text << std::setw(60) << mantissa_with_leading_digit_value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::setw(50) << mantissa_with_leading_digit_value << " * 2**" << std::setw(5) << exponent_value << "   =   " << std::setw(12) << mantissa_with_leading_digit_value*std::pow(2.0F,exponent_value) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::setw(180) << std::setfill('-') << '\n' << std::setfill(' ') << "\n\n\n";

    return os;
}

int main()
{
    double max_double = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
    double lowest_double = std::numeric_limits<double>::min();
    double stored_value{0.4543543234343654632452452525254e-323};


    MyMap values{
        {"Lowest",std::make_tuple(lowest_double, convert_to_string(lowest_double))},
        {"Highest",std::make_tuple(max_double, convert_to_string(max_double))},
        {"0.4543543234343654632452452525254e-323",std::make_tuple(stored_value, convert_to_string(stored_value))}

    };

    std::cout << std::setw(60) << "Variable name" << std::setw(20) << "Decimal value" << std::setw(10) << "Sign" << std::setw(15) << "Exponent" << std::setw(10) << "Exp. Rule" << std::setw(60) << "Mantissa" << std::setw(30) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::setw(180) << std::setfill('-') << '\n' << std::setfill(' ');
    for (auto& i : values)
        std::cout << i;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
                                               Variable name       Decimal value      Sign       Exponent Exp. Rule                                                    Mantissa
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                      Lowest        2.22507e-308
   Binary  (biased   exponent, hidden  leading binary digit)                             0    00000000001                  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   Binary  (unbiased exponent, visible leading binary digit)                             0   -01111111110                1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   Decimal (biased   exponent)                                                           +              1                                                                     1
   Decimal (unbiased exponent)                                                           +          -1022                                                                     1
                                                 1 * 2**-1022   =   2.22507e-308
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



                                                     Highest        1.79769e+308
   Binary  (biased   exponent, hidden  leading binary digit)                             0    11111111110                  1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
   Binary  (unbiased exponent, visible leading binary digit)                             0    01111111111                1.1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
   Decimal (biased   exponent)                                                           +           2046                                                                     2
   Decimal (unbiased exponent)                                                           +           1023                                                                     2
                                                 2 * 2** 1023   =   1.79769e+308
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



                      0.4543543234343654632452452525254e-323        4.94066e-324
   Binary  (biased   exponent, hidden  leading binary digit)                             0    00000000000  denormal        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
   Binary  (unbiased exponent, visible leading binary digit)                             0   -01111111110  denormal      0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
   Decimal (biased   exponent)                                                           +              0  denormal                                                 2.22045e-16
   Decimal (unbiased exponent)                                                           +          -1022  denormal                                                 2.22045e-16
                                       2.22045e-16 * 2**-1022   =   4.94066e-324
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```